# Count the number of occurrences of a substring in a string

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

How can I count the number of occurrences of a substring in a string using Bash?

**EXAMPLE:**

I'd like to know how many times this substring...

```
Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
```

...occurs in this string...

```
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
113: hci0: Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
```

**NOTE I:** I have tried several approaches with sed, grep, awk... Nothing seems to work when we have strings with spaces and multiple lines.

**NOTE II:** I'm a Linux user and I'm trying a solution that does not involve installing applications/tools outside those that are usually found in Linux distributions.

---

**IMPORTANT:**

In addition to my question it is possible to have something according to the hypothetical example below. In this case instead of using files we use two Shell variables (Bash).

EXAMPLE: (based on @Ed Morton contribution)

```
STRING="0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
113: hci0: Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no"

SUB_STRING="Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no"

awk -v RS='\0' 'NR==FNR{str=$0; next} {print gsub(str,"")}' "$STRING" "$SUB_STRING"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update given your comments below, if the white space is the same in both strings:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print gsub(ARGV[2],"",ARGV[1])}' "$STRING" "$SUB_STRING"
```

or if the white space is different as in your example where the STRING lines start with 9 blanks but SUB_STRING with 8:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"[[:space:]]+",ARGV[2]); print gsub(ARGV[2],"",ARGV[1])}' "$STRING" "$SUB_STRING"
```

---

Original answer:

With GNU awk if your white-space matched between files and the search string doesn't contain RE metachars all you'd need is:

```
awk -v RS='^$' 'NR==FNR{str=$0; next} {print gsub(str,"")}' str file
```

or with any awk if your input also doesn't contain NUL chars:

```
awk -v RS='\0' 'NR==FNR{str=$0; next} {print gsub(str,"")}' str file
```

but for a full solution with explanations, read on:

With any POSIX awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ cat str
Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

$ awk '
NR==FNR { str=(str=="" ? "" : str ORS) $0; next }
{ rec=(rec=="" ? "" : rec ORS) $0 }
END {
    gsub(/[^[:space:]]/,"[&]",str) # make sure each non-space char is treated as literal
    gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"[[:space:]]+",str) # make sure space differences do not matter
    print gsub(str,"",rec)
}
' str file
2
```

With a non-POSIX awk like nawk just use `0-9` instead of `[:space:]`. If your search string can contain backslashes then we'd need to add 1 more gsub() to handle them.

Alternatively, with GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' 'NR==FNR{gsub(/[^[:space:]]/,"[&]"); gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"[[:space:]]+"); str=$0; next} {print gsub(str,"")}' str file
2
```

or with any awk if your input cannot contain NUL chars:

```
$ awk -v RS='\0' 'NR==FNR{gsub(/[^[:space:]]/,"[&]"); gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"[[:space:]]+"); str=$0; next} {print gsub(str,"")}' str file
2
```

and on and on...

Comment: thank you very much for your contributions. However, I would like something like this: `awk -v RS='\0' 'NR==FNR{str=$0; next} {print gsub(str,"")}' "$STRING" "$SUB_STRING"`. See the modification I made in my question for more details.

Comment: Many thanks, but the `awk 'BEGIN{print gsub(ARGV[2],"",ARGV[1])}' "$STRING" "$SUB_STRING"` code returns 0.

Comment: Right, that's because in the example you posted there are fewer blanks at the start of each line of SUB_STRING (8) than at the start of each line of STRING (9), that's why I posted the 2nd script which accommodates differences in white space.

Comment: Great answer. However, at this point, I can not accept it because we can have any number of spaces before and after each line in the substring. In my case, we need the count to be made by the exact substring entered. =D

Comment: Hang on. What the heck are you talking about? The example you provided does not have the same number of spaces in the substring as the string. Your question implies that SHOULD be a match and now your comment implies that should NOT be a match. I gave you scripts that will work in either scenario and now you're saying that neither do whatever it is you want. I am extremely confused about what it is you're trying to do. Please update your question to make it **far** clearer and specifically show why neither of the 2 scripts at the top of my answer work for whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: "The example you provided does not have the same number of spaces in the substring as the string." -> Yes! You are right! I have already corrected the number of spaces in "SUB_STRING". Your approach `awk 'BEGIN{print gsub(ARGV[2],"",ARGV[1])}' "$STRING" "$SUB_STRING"` works perfectly! Your answer is correct! Sorry for the confusion! Thanks a lot! =D

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { RS="[0-9]+:" }      # number followed by colon is the record separator
NR==1 {                     # read the substring to b
    b=$0
    next
}
$0~b { c++ }                # if b matches current record, increment counter
END { print c }             # print counter value
' substringfile stringfile
2
```

This solution requires that the match is identical to the amount of space and your example would not work as-is since the substring has less space in the indention than the string. Notice that due to the chosen `RS` matching for example `phy0:` is not possible; in that case something like `RS="(^|\n)[0-9]+:"` would probably work.

Another:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN{ RS="^$" }                           # treat whole files as one record
NR==1 { b=$0; next }                       # buffer substringfile
{
    while(match($0,b)) {                   # count matches of b in stringfile
        $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH-1)
        c++
    }
}
END { print c }                            # output
' substringfile stringfile
```

**Edit**: Sure, remove the `BEGIN` section and use Bash's process substitution like below:

```
$ awk '
NR==1 { 
    b=$0
    gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",b)                 # clean surrounding space from substring
    next 
}
{
    while(match($0,b)) {
        $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH-1)
        c++
    }
}
END { print c }
' <(echo $SUB_STRING) <(echo $STRING)    # feed it with process substitution
2
```

`echo`ing  in process substitution flattens the data and removes duplicate spaces too:

```
$ echo $SUB_STRING
Bluetooth Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no
```

so the space problem should ease up a bit.

**Edit2**: Based on @EdMorton's hawk-eyed observation in the comments:

```
$ awk '
NR==1 { 
    b=$0
    gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",b)                 # clean surrounding space from substring
    next 
}
{ print gsub(b,"") }
' <(echo $SUB_STRING) <(echo $STRING)    # feed it with process substitution
2
```

Comment: Good one! However I'd like to be able to use Shell variables (Bash) (see the modification in my question). Is there any way to do this? Thanks! =D

Comment: Your answer is almost perfect, though I can not accept it at the moment because if there are differences in spaces between the STRING and the SUB_STRING we will have a false answer 2 when in reality the strings are different. For example, if we have `STRING="Soft blocked: no"` and `SUB_STRING="         Soft blocked: no"` the script will return 2. We need a "match" by the exact string. Thanks a lot! =D

Comment: Just add `gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",b)` after the `b=$0 'to clean leading and trailing space from the substring. `echo` removes the duplicates and `substring` will match the `string` with surrounding space. Next step would be approximate pattern matching.

Comment: FYI `{
    while(match($0,b)) {                   # count matches of b in stringfile
        $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH-1)
        c++
    }
}
END { print c }` is equivalent to using just `{print gsub(b,"")}`. Also, I think the OP is saying the opposite of what you think and he does NOT want leading/trailing blanks to be removed (which is what we all assumed in the first place so idk why it's coming up now!). It's all very confusing...

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, it really is, lol! Thanks. I'll add yet another piece to the chain of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this with GNU grep:

```
grep -zo -P ".*Bluetooth\n\s*Soft blocked: no\n\s*Hard blocked: no" <your_file> | grep -c "Bluetooth"
```

The first grep will match on multiple lines and display only matched groups. Counting occurrences of Bluetooth from that match will give you count of matched 'substring'.

Output of first grep:

```
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
113: hci0: Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
```

Output of entire command:

```
2
```

Comment: Many thanks @Vivek Pabani, but I think there is a problem in your answer. We have to escape the string which modifies the amount of spaces and, additionally, we would have to have some functionality to automate this process. Other than that I'd like to be able to use Shell variables (Bash) (see the modification and my question)!

Comment: What do you mean by escape amount of space? Could you show what your expected result is from your example?

Comment: I'll try to explain better. For example, AFAIK if my entry is `"         Soft blocked: no"` or `"Soft blocked: no"` with the value `"\s*Soft blocked: no"` match result becomes indifferent to the spaces of the original string entered. Thanks! =D

Comment: So, do you want to match the exact space in substring to the string?

Comment: If it is possible, yes! =D

Answer (score 0):

Use python:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as i:
    print(len(re.findall(sys.argv[2], i.read(), re.MULTILINE)))
```

invoke as

```
$ ./search.py file.txt 'Bluetooth
 +Soft blocked: no
 +Hard blocked: no'
```

the `+` allows one or more spaces.

### EDIT

If the content is already in bash variables it's even simpler

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re

print(len(re.findall(sys.argv[2], sys.argv[1], re.MULTILINE)))
```

invoke as

```
$ ./search.py "$STRING" "$SUB_STRING"
```

Comment: Great answer! However (in my case) we need the count to be made by the exact substring entered. Other than that I'd like to be able to use Shell variables (Bash) (see the modification in my question). If we can use this Python code inside the bash script itself, then it would be perfect. Thanks! =D

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & wc):

```
sed -nr 'N;/^(\s*)Soft( blocked: no\s*)\n\1Hard\2$/P;D' file | wc -l
```

Output a line for each occurrence of the multi-line match and count the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Another awk

```
awk '
  NR==FNR{
    b[i++]=$0          # get each line of string in array b
    next}
  $0 ~ b[0]{            # if current record match first line of string
    for(j=1;j<i;j++){
      getline
      if($0!~b[j])  # next record do not match break
        j+=i}
     if(j==i)         # all record match string
       k++}
  END{
    print k}
' stringfile infile
```

EDIT :

And for the XY problem of the OP, a simple script :

cat scriptbash.sh

```
list="${1//$'\n'/@}"
var="${2//$'\n'/@}"
result="${list//$var}"
echo $(((${#list} - ${#result}) / ${#var}))
```

And you call it like that :

./scriptbash.sh "$String" "$Sub_String"

Comment: I'd like to be able to use Shell variables (Bash) (see the modification in my question)! Is there any way to do this? Thanks! =D